# Custom sorting in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to sort the data and I want to sort the data based on Ship to the country column.

```
Waybill #       Fob Code Order Type               Ship To Country
-----------------------------------------------------------------
PEN00070420     FCA POE  SGS-541                  DE    
SPM-SCRAP       FCA POE  SGS-541                  SG    
DIM027-055239   FCA POE  SGS-541                  SG    
DIM027-055085   FCA POE  SGS-541                  HK    
DIM027-054845   FCA POE  SGS-541                  HK    
F722954503      FCA POE  USO-821                  US    
ATKDGFHKG0163   FCA POE  SGS-541                  US    
PEN452450420    FCA POE  SGS-541                  DE
```

I need this dataset as my result:

```
Waybill #       Fob Code Order Type               Ship To Country
-----------------------------------------------------------------
PEN00070420     FCA POE  SGS-541                  DE    
DIM027-055085   FCA POE  SGS-541                  HK    
SPM-SCRAP       FCA POE  SGS-541                  SG    
F722954503      FCA POE  USO-821                  US    
PEN452450420    FCA POE  SGS-541                  DE    
DIM027-054845   FCA POE  SGS-541                  HK    
DIM027-055239   FCA POE  SGS-541                  SG    
ATKDGFHKG0163   FCA POE  SGS-541                  US
```

Here `DE`, `SG`, `HK`, `US` are repeating and this goes on and on repeatedly. How to perform this kind of sorting in SQL Server?

Comment: `order by ShipToCountry`?

Comment: Your resultant table is not ordering by ship to country? Please explain the logic.

Comment: You want to show one row from each country and then repeat until you run out of rows? What happens when countries don't have the same number of rows?

Comment: Why would DIM027-055085 precede DIM027-054845?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
order by row_number() over (partition by shipto order by waybill),
         shipto
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to order them twice.

1. Once by partitioning by shipTocountry and Order by ShipToCountry. Now, you get ranking at shipToCountry partitions
2. In the results of Step no. 1, you have to again order them, based on ShipTocountry, to list the countries of a rank in order.

```sql
DECLARE @table table(waybill VARCHAR(30),Febcode VARCHAR(30),OrderType VARCHAR(30), ShipTocountry VARCHAR(30))

INSERT INTO @table values

('PEN00070420  ','FCA POE','SGS-541','DE'),    
('SPM-SCRAP    ','FCA POE','SGS-541','SG'),    
('DIM027-055239','FCA POE','SGS-541','SG'),    
('DIM027-055085','FCA POE','SGS-541','HK'),    
('DIM027-054845','FCA POE','SGS-541','HK'),    
('F722954503   ','FCA POE','USO-821','US'),    
('ATKDGFHKG0163','FCA POE','SGS-541','US'),    
('PEN452450420 ','FCA POE','SGS-541','DE');

SELECT Waybill, Febcode, OrderType, ShipTocountry
FROM
(
SELECT Waybill, Febcode, OrderType, ShipTocountry,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER  (PARTITION BY ShipToCountry ORDER BY shipToCountry) as rnk
from @table
) as t
order by rnk,ShipTocountry
```

```
+---------------+---------+-----------+---------------+
|    Waybill    | Febcode | OrderType | ShipTocountry |
+---------------+---------+-----------+---------------+
| PEN00070420   | FCA POE | SGS-541   | DE            |
| DIM027-055085 | FCA POE | SGS-541   | HK            |
| SPM-SCRAP     | FCA POE | SGS-541   | SG            |
| F722954503    | FCA POE | USO-821   | US            |
| PEN452450420  | FCA POE | SGS-541   | DE            |
| DIM027-054845 | FCA POE | SGS-541   | HK            |
| DIM027-055239 | FCA POE | SGS-541   | SG            |
| ATKDGFHKG0163 | FCA POE | SGS-541   | US            |
+---------------+---------+-----------+---------------+
```